# Registration and insurance for gift car

Tags: car, car-insurance

Our 30-year-old nephew lives with us. He is about to receive a used car as a gift. My wife and I each own a car, and all three of us are listed as insured drivers.

- Is it best to include his car in our insurance, or should we shop around for his own policy?
- Is it best to put his name on the title and/or registration, or one of ours instead?

EDIT: More details: We live in California. He's been on our insurance since he was a minor and learned to drive; I don't know if there's a financial advantage to adding the car and keeping him, or having him separate from our policy and get his own.

The gift-giver was about to fill out the transfer forms and asked me whose name should go on the title. The "obvious" answer could be wrong for all I know, so I'm asking if there are financial, legal, or practical aspects that I may not have thought of.

Comment: The obvious first question is "why won't he buy his own insurance?"

Comment: The second question is, "**why are you thinking of taking his car?**  Because that's what your second question is asking.

Comment: Even if he lives with you, it surely is better to have his stuff separated from yours in terms of independence, even if it is just a psychological thing.

Comment: @RonJohn 1) My insurance company provides multi-car and multi-driver discounts. I'm hoping you folks can tell me whether that's good enough reason. 2) The gift-giver asked me whether to put the title in my name or my nephew's. If there are pros and cons other than the obvious, I'd like to know.

Comment: A crucial comment of mine was removed.  We need to know **why** OP is asking about this before we can even think about providing competent answers.

Comment: @RonJohn My previous comment responded to your two comments

Comment: No, Shawn, they didn't.  At age 30 I was just getting back on my feet after a couple of years of underemployment, so a gift car would have been appreciated.  But to have the "adults" treat me like a 16 year old would have been insulting.  **There's something you aren't telling us**, and it's why you've only received one generic answer.

Comment: Is it even possible to put someone who is 30 years old, and not your child, on your auto insurance?

Comment: @jamesqf He's been on our insurance since he learned to drive.

Comment: He's **30** and not paying his own way.  You're **not** telling us something important.

Comment: @RonJohn Like I said originally, he's underemployed so i'm helping him out. If that's what you mean, i don't see why it matters. If not, I  really don't know *what* else could be relevant.

Comment: @ShawnV.Wilson no, you **didn't** say he's underemployed.  **I** said that about **myself**.

Comment: "*I really don't know what else could be relevant.*" Why you're treating a 30 year old like minor.

Comment: @RonJohn I didn't use that word, but I did say...never mind. The fact is, how I "treat" him is a subject for the Interpersonal SE. Here, I'm looking for financial, practical, and possibly legal considerations of the best thing to do. But thanks for watching out for my nephew.

Comment: As I wrote yesterday, "We need to know why OP is asking about this **before we can** even think about **providing competent answers**."

Answer (score 2):

You’ll need to decide for yourselves which is best, but here are a couple of things to consider:

- Do you want to tie a potential discount on your nephew’s policy to a potential hike in premiums if he makes a claim?
- Do you want the responsibility for his car that goes along with its ownership?